# Firebase-RealTime-Database Listener vs WebAPI-Request

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 Android Apps involved in a Food Car-Delivery Service:

> 1- Driver.App : an App running on a Device in the Car (driver)
>   delivering the food.

The Driver.App is notifying the GPS position to a WebAPI Server where the position (lat,lng) is stored on a SQL-DB.
The Driver.App notifies this position every 2-5 seconds... depends on the settings but mainly every 3 seconds.

> 2- Customer.App : an App where the Customer track the position on a
>   Map of the food delivery.

The Customer.App requests to the WebAPI every 5 seconds where it tracks the latest position of the car delivering the food.

I am considering changing this WebAPI solution (explain above) to use **Firebase Realtime Database** instead. I really need the expertise of this community in order to understand the pros and cons that I must face.

The new idea (with Firebase) is to have the Customer.App subscribed to a Driver.App.Locations (Firebase.DB) and so the Customer will not need to keep requesting and doing http-calls to the WebAPI.

The Driver.App will notify the changes to Firebase and so Firebase will notify the updates to the Customers.App.

I have 3 questions in regards the **Customer.App Battery**:

1. Doing the WebAPI request... how bad is it to do this? How much battery will consume the WebAPI request every 5 seconds considering that the result/response JSON is around 500 bytes. Will that be an issue with the App and the Battery?
2. Using Firebase, how much REALLY efficiency will be listening and receiving the updates from the Firebase every time the Driver updates the locations instead of doing the http-request every 5 seconds?
3. Is there any other better suggestion to be implemented?

I would like to know the pros/cons of doing the WebAPI-Http-Request instead of being listening while subscribed to the Firebase, of course knowing the the Delivery.Car is moving and so is generating new locations every time.

Comment: You can go with Socket connections.. Customer and Driver both connected via sockets.. I believe that when rate of transmitting data is high, sockets would work fastest and would be battery efficient too.